# Currency selector in RWD mobile view not working correctly

Tags: rwd-theme

The currency dropdown when viewing the RWD theme on mobile or smaller screens (the one that shows up at the bottom of the screen) seems to select by default the wrong currency.

For example - I have £ and € available. When prices on the site are displayed in £ it pre-selects € so that I am unable to select € to change the currency to.

This doesn't happen with the currency dropdown at the top of the site.